# OMXCodec.cpp error compiling Gingerbread from codeaurora.org

Tags: android, compilation, android-source, android-2.3-gingerbread, stagefright

After downloading the entire Android source code for Gingerbread from the codeaurora.org Git repository, I'm getting a compile error.

It has to do with the OMXCodec.cpp file in /frameworks/base/media/libstagefright

Does anyone have a feasible workaround?  I have replaced the libstagefright directory with a tarball that I downloaded, but to no avail.